# Laravel queue:work command uses wrong data when a lot of parallel jobs are running

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, laravel-8

I am struggling with a problem nobody was able to help me in the past.

I am using Laravel 8 (newest version) and PHP 8 (newest version from odrej ppa). So far so good. My application is very big and handles approximately 3-4 millions jobs per day. We have xxx servers running - so scaling is not an issue. Queue gets handeled fast enought.

A simple supervisor configuration is used:

https://pastebin.com/rALV2q58

Now finally to the problem itself:

From the frontend I can start a Job called "Requester", the job class is quite simple:

https://pastebin.com/77QBVzB8

As you can see, I basically generate somewhere else a command and then it gets called via Artisan::call. Straight forward. The command itself is basically just:

`php artisan requester:start --target=[ID] --url=[Url] --ua=[User-Agent]`

**Command class:** https://pastebin.com/03PLpByg

**Now imagine** I add 10000 different jobs of this kind into queue system (I am using a dedicated redis server). Via logging I can track, that all jobs are queued, and then processed by our servers.

Lets say we add a big batch of jobs which are basically requesting:

`http://test1.com (with user agent ua1)`

`http://test2.com (with user agent ua1)`

`http://test3.com (with user agent ua1)`

`http://test4.com (with user agent ua1)`

`http://test5.com (with user agent ua1)`

... [10000]

Queuesystem starts.

We **immidiately start another 10000 jobs** (so we have ~20000 jobs in our queue system), but this time other urls and other user agent string:

`http://abc1.com (with user agent abc1)`

`http://abc2.com (with user agent abc1)`

`http://abc3.com (with user agent abc1)`

`http://abc4.com (with user agent abc1)`

`http://abc5.com (with user agent abc1)`

... [10000]

Thats basically our setup (I tried to minimize it as far as possible).

When we observe the traffic on all our 20000 domains the system currently is requesting, we see that after a short amount of time **the data gets mixed up:**

`http://test1.com gets requested with user agent: abc1 (instead of ua1)`

`http://test2.com gets requested with user agent: abc1 (instead of ua1)`

`http://abc2.com gets requested with user agent: ua1 (instead of abc1)`

`http://abc3.com gets requested with user agent: ua1 (instead of abc1)`

`http://abc4.com gets requested with user agent: ua1 (instead of abc1)`

... [10000]

Thats basically my problem. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. All variables are protected.

**I have simple solution:**

Instead of using queue:work, I have to switch to queue:listen.

**But:**
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues

```
Alternatively, you may run the queue:listen command. When using the queue:listen command, 
you don't have to manually restart the worker when you want to reload your updated code or
reset the application state; however, this command is significantly less efficient than 
the queue:work command:
```

I benchmarked it and queue:work is significantly faster, thats why I would love to use queue:work instead of queue:listen in production.

By the way we had that behaviour in PHP 7 as well as in Laravel 5.8+.

Maybe one of you can help me out and point me to the right direction - till now nobody was able to help me.

Best,

Damian

Comment: Faced the same issue. We also have a lot of jobs per day ( ~ 150k ) and for some of them I catch wrong input data. It doesn't look like some code mistake, this data looks like the data from another job. Queue restart solves the problem, but only for few hours. It looks like some kind of cache and it works wrong.

Comment: Hey,I actually figured it out - was a hard road but ultimately if was necessary to refactor our entire codebase. The first problem is that one should NOT use artisan::call within jobs. Simple as that. Thats why I created "Tasks" for each command. That way I could use the Task class within my job as well as within my artisan class. Another keypoint is to have private instead of protected attributes within jobs. All was worth it because now the entire job queting and processing is fast as hell! <3 Community wise... nobody at laravel could help me...

Comment: The more jobs you have, the more issues of this kind will appear - learnt my lesson. What you write makes sense, since queue:listen basically restarts itself after every job exec, that way you dont have mixed data.

Comment: In my case I couldn't avoid of calling Artisan::queue, so I've made several experiments. At the end for me helped manual resetting issued class properties at the end of the handle() method, e.g. $this->property = null; or $this->property = 'defaultvalue'. If the property is object, it should be nullable. After that the problem has gone.